# Java JTextField and non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java

My error is on line 23-24. non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context

I know why I am getting the error but I don't know how to fix it in this case:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.AWTEvent;
    import java.awt.MouseInfo;
    import java.awt.Toolkit;

    public class VideoGamerEvent implements ActionListener {
        VideoGamer gui;
        String theEvent;
        String theCoords;

        public VideoGamerEvent(VideoGamer in){
            gui = in;
        }


        public static class Listener implements AWTEventListener {
            public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
                System.out.print(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation() + " | ");
                System.out.println(event);

//error here
                theEvent = event.toString();
                theCoords = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().toString();
//end error

            }
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if(theEvent.contains("FOCUS_LOST")){
                gui.coords.setText(theCoords);
            }    
        }
    }
```

I need to eventually get theCoords into a JTextField (gui.coords).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the variables for static:

```
static String theEvent;
static String theCoords;
```

and then this error will disappear.

Comment: No, no, no, please don't suggest the use of static in this manner. The OP should either be passing the values to the instance of the class, provide getters and/or setters or use a third/model class. This kind of advice just causes bad practices and long term problems which will need to be corrected in the future, and I don't like telling people that the previous advice they got was bad or wrong, especially from a professional forum

Answer (score 2):

You could...

- Provide getters in the `Listener` which return the values
- Provide an [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) to the `Listener` which would then provide notificaiton to interested parties about changes to the state of the `Listener`, from which they could then inspect the values via the getters
- Use a "model" style class which could be used to set/get the values from and which could implement the [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) as suggested above

As a side note, you would need a very specific reason for using `AWTEventListener`, when you could simply use a `MouseListener` or `MouseMotionListener` to achieve the same results